# Get the id of element focus is moving to in jQuery.blur event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've written some code using jQuery to do an ajax call and display a message on the page when the user moves focus away from a field.  My field is called `txtLogin` and the user types in some text and clicks a button to create a new user account in a database using the given `txtLogin` value.

The issue is that a valid value must contain four letters, a dash, and then four more letters.  My client insists that the form should have two fields, one for the first four letters, and another for the second four letters.

Suppose that these two fields are called `txtLogin0` and `txtLogin1`.  I still want to do an ajax call when the user moves focus away from the field, but the ajax call should not be invoked when the user moves from one of the two fields to the other!

My current code looks like this.

```
$('#txtLogin').blur(function() {
    var login = $(this).val();
    var isValid = testLogin(login);
    if (!isValid) alert('Login is invalid');
});
```

I imagine my new code looking like this:

```
$('#txtLogin0').add('#txtLogin1').blur(function() {
    var focusId = The Id of the newly focused element
    if (focusId==='txtLogin0' || focusId==='txtLogin1) return
    var login = $(#txtLogin0').val() + '-' + $('#txtLogin1').val();
    var isValid = testLogin(login);
    if (!isValid) alert('Login is invalid');
});
```

How can I get the id of the element that the focus moves to in the jQuery.blur event?

Comment: The new element isn't focused yet, therefore you won't be able to know what element is getting focused using just a blur event.

Answer (score 1):

A simple hack is to create two var to store the current and previous element in `onfocus` and `onblur` and call the validate method inside a timer which will be triggered in 0 milli seconds.. Try below code and I think it is close to what you want.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/WY539/4/)

```
var prevEl, curEl;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#txtLogin0, #txtLogin1').blur(function() {
        prevEl = this.id;

        setTimeout(validateLogin, 0);

    }).focus(function() {
        curEl = this.id;
    });
});

function validateLogin() {
    if ((prevEl === 'txtLogin0' && curEl === 'txtLogin1') || (curEl === 'txtLogin0' && prevEl === 'txtLogin1')) {
        return;
    }
    prevEl = ''; curEl = '';
    var login = $('#txtLogin0').val() + '-' + $('#txtLogin1').val();
    var isValid = testLogin(login);
    if (!isValid) alert('Login is invalid');
}

function testLogin(txt) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is this code supposed to make the $(document).blur fire when just anything is clicked?  The function only runs when the page first loads.

Comment: @RiceFlourCookies Did you try the demo, the `validateLogin` will be called everytime you blur from `txtLogin0` and `txtLogin1`.

Answer (score -2):

```
var focusId = $(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: That returns the id of the blured element.